# Pop Ups in a PDF

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, vtiger

I have html rendered on a page using a vtiger plugin called PDFMaker. It basically takes HTML and renders it in a downloadable pdf. Is there anyway to have javascript or some type of interactive code through the PDF? Is there documentation on this? Oh and an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for JavaScript working in PDF is the JavaScript section of the Acrobat SDK documentation. The Acrobat SDK can be downloaded from the Adobe website.

Keep in mind that besides the JavaScript Core, you can forget what you have learned with JavaScript for webbrowsers.

If that vtiger plugin does not allow to pre-define JavaScript, you would have the possibility to create an FDF file and to inject (document-level) JavaScript with it.